# use querySelectorAll to create a loop for newly created elements

Tags: javascript, loops, indexing, selectors-api

What I'm trying to do is use the `querySelectorAll()` function to create a loop where I can target each new `<li/>` element that I've created using the `getInput()` function that I created (which works fine). I wanted to use `console.log()` to test this, so that when I click on each `<li/>` item it confirms that I have done so in the console. This `querySelectorAll()` method is new to me and I'm also new at learning Javascript in general. So, any advice and explanation would be very helpful. thanks.

```
function getInput() {
    var liValue = theForm.elements.input.value;  
    var liNew = document.createElement("li");
    liNew.innerHTML += liValue;
    var list = document.getElementById("ulList");
    list.appendChild(liNew); 
    deleteLi;
 }

 function deleteLi() {
    var handlers = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < handlers.lenghth; i++) {
        handlers[i].onclick = console.log("you got me");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you considered just adding a CSS class to the newly created nodes for this purpose?

Comment: I'm maybe missing something obvious, but I don't quite understand what you want us to help with. What's going wrong in your current code?

Comment: Maybe it's just `handlers.lenghth`, that should be `handlers.length`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the spelling error. I'm trying to use queryselectorall to capture all of the li elements i'm making. then i wanted to use a loop that i could use to point to each li individually. i was trying to use console.log to point to each one to test if I had been able to do that, because after I know that I am actually targeting each one I want to later add the ability to delete each one when I click on each of them specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the click handler when you create the element.  Running qSA as you have posted with select all `li` elements, even those you have already created.

```
function getInput() {
    var liValue = theForm.elements.input.value;  
    var liNew = document.createElement("li");
    liNew.onclick = function() { console.log("clicked!"); };
    liNew.innerHTML += liValue;
    var list = document.getElementById("ulList");
    list.appendChild(liNew); 
}
```